# 3 constructors that accept 3 different types of arguments

Tags: c#

As I understand, the constructor chaining can be applied to cases when we have some common data to initialize. I have 3 constructors that accept 3 different types of arguments and have some common data. I'm not sure if I can do constructor chaining.

```
public class RStandart
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _objConn;
    private readonly RequestData _requestData = new RequestData();

    public string CardNo { get; set; }
    public string PaymentType { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }

    public class RequestData
    {
        // Request data (just a properties}
    }

    public RequestData GetRequestData
    {
        get { return _requestData; }
    }

    public RStandart(Int64 orderID, string total)
    {
        _requestData.VpcVirtualPaymentClientURL = string.Format("https://{0}/vpcpay", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_VirtualPaymentClientURL"]);
        _requestData.VpcVersion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_Version"];
        _requestData.VpcCommand = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_Command"];
        _requestData.VpcAccessCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_AccessCode"];
        _requestData.VpcOrderInfo = orderID;
        _requestData.VpcMerchant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_Merchant"];
        _requestData.VpcAmount = int.Parse(total.Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace(",", string.Empty));
        _requestData.VpcLocale = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_Locale"];
        _requestData.VpcReturnURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_ReturnURL"];
        _requestData.RequestParams = string.Format(
            "vpc_Version-{0}|vpc_Command-{1}|vpc_AccessCode-{2}|vpc_MerchTxnRef-{3}|vpc_Merchant-{4}|vpc_Amount-{5}|vpc_Locale-{6}|vpc_ReturnURL-{7}|vpc_OrderInfo-{8}",
            _requestData.VpcVersion, _requestData.VpcCommand, _requestData.VpcAccessCode, _requestData.VpcMerchTxnRef, _requestData.VpcMerchant,
            _requestData.VpcAmount.ToString(), _requestData.VpcLocale, _requestData.VpcReturnURL, _requestData.VpcOrderInfo);
        _requestData.VpcSecureHash = GetMD5(SortParamStr(_requestData.RequestParams), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_SecureHash"]);
    }

    public RStandart(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        _objConn = conn;
        SetDefaultValues();

        _requestData.VpcVirtualPaymentClientURL = string.Format("https://{0}/vpcdps", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_VirtualPaymentClientURL"]);
        _requestData.VpcVersion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_Version"];
        _requestData.VpcCommand = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_CommandDR"];
        _requestData.VpcAccessCode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_AccessCode"];
        _requestData.VpcMerchant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_Merchant"];
        _requestData.VpcUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_User"];
        _requestData.VpcPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_Password"];
        _requestData.RequestParams = string.Format(
            "vpc_Version={0}&vpc_Command={1}&vpc_AccessCode={2}&vpc_MerchTxnRef={3}&vpc_Merchant={4}&vpc_User={5}&vpc_Password={6}",
            _requestData.VpcVersion, _requestData.VpcCommand, _requestData.VpcAccessCode, _requestData.VpcMerchTxnRef,
            _requestData.VpcMerchant, _requestData.VpcUser, _requestData.VpcPassword);
    }

    public RStandart(HttpRequest request)
    {
        string vpc_SH = Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_SecureHash");
        var query = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string key in request.QueryString.Keys)
        {
            if ((key != "rsCheck") && (key != "vpc_SecureHash"))
            {
                query.AppendFormat("{0}-{1}|", key, Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, key));
            }
        }
        _requestData.VpcSecureHash = GetMD5(SortParamStr(query.ToString().Substring(0, query.ToString().Length - 1)), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["vpc_SecureHash"]);
        if (_requestData.VpcSecureHash.ToUpper() == vpc_SH)
        {
            int respCode = Query.GetIntQueryParam(request, "vpc_TxnResponseCode");
            _requestData.VpcMessage = Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_Message");

            if ((respCode == 0) && (_requestData.VpcMessage.IndexOf("Approved") > -1))
            {
                _requestData.VpcOrderInfo = Query.GetIntQueryParam(request, "vpc_OrderInfo");
                Total = double.Parse(Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_Amount").Length > 2
                                        ? Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_Amount")
                                            .Insert(Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_Amount").Length - 2, ",")
                                        : "0," + Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_Amount"));
                TransactionDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_BatchNo"))
                                        ? DateTime.Now
                                        : DateTime.Parse(
                                            Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_BatchNo")
                                                .Insert(6, "-")
                                                .Insert(4, "-"));
                TransactionId = Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_TransactionNo");
                CardNo = Query.GetStrQueryParam(request, "vpc_CardNum");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also not sure if I should have `RequestData` class as nested class or it should be out of `RStandard` class, but in the same namespace.

Comment: What are you doing with `_requestData` after forging it in the constructor? And with `_objConn`?

Comment: I use it in public GetRequestData property. I've updated the original vode. Please, check it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use constructor chaining on the first two constructors but the last one differs a lot.

What i think is more important is that you  give the RStandart class a lot of knowledge and responsibility to setup the RequestData class. Are you sure this class needs to know how to initialize a RequestData class?

I would move all the code that depends on the ConfigurationManager to the RequestData class and it in turn would make your constructors simpler and you would remove that duplicate code.

Comment: It's interesting suggestion about configuration data. Do you think I should leave RequestData class as nested or to be out of RStandard class?

Comment: You can still keep your RequestData class as I'm sure it has more then what you are showing here :), but i would move it into a separate file as i always do that. At least in my mind that makes it easier to use and find later

Comment: But, DataRequest class uses some private methods from outside RStandard class.

Comment: I'm not entierly sure on what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean RStandard and RequestData classes use the same private methods. If RequestData class is nested into RStandard class it's ok. But, if RequestData class would be out of RStandard class as you suggest, I would double these methods.

Answer (score 3):

### Information

You can do constructor chaining in C#. However what you are doing here does not require such techniques. Here in your case you have 3 constructors taking all different types of data, and mostly doing separate things.

You will be best off grouping repeated code into a method and calling that method from each constructor that needs it.

However, for future reference if you do want to do real constructor chaining, you can do it as such...

```
public RStandart(string something, string anotherThing)
{
    // I do something!
}

public RStandart(object somethingElse)
    :this("none", somethingElse.ToString())
{
    //This code runs after the first constructor is called.
}
```

### Review

I don't know if this is something you should implement, because I don't know how you intend to use this class. In C# you can place access modifiers on the individual parts of the getters and setters. A way you can use this (again, not sure if you need to, but this is isncase you do):

```
public string CardNo { get; private set; }
```

Now your CardNo cannot be changed outside the scope of this class. This should be done any time you don't want something to be changed from an outside source. This doesn't work well with objects, because.. while the reference cannot be changed, the object its self can be, so you'll have to be careful there.

Comment: *This doesn't work well with objects* ...except `System.String` which is immutable, of course ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I almost said `except immutable objects`, but I took the lazy road, and didn't bother to mention it, because there are other niche cases... and yah I was just being silly. I should have just said `"The object its self can be, if it has public modifiable members"`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, constructor chaining is useful in cases where you want to initialize your object to some default value and set specific value of properties/ members as the number of parameters increases.
In your class you can create a private default constructor to place some of the common code, however in this creating a method makes more sense.